# Issue with cursor retrieving values

Tags: plsql, cursor

I am trying to use a cursor for the following block of code, but it is not compiling and giving error saying the following:

```
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
```

All the trxn table values are being fetched, Does anyone have faced similar error before? Any way this can be fixed or am I missing something?

```
I am trying to use a cursor for the following block of code, but it is not compiling and giving error saying the following:

PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
```

All the trxn table values are being fetched, Does anyone have faced similar error before? Any way this can be fixed or am I missing something?

```
cursor bulk_select is 
with trxn as (
    select --+ materialize
        -- Wire info
        wt.id
        ,wt.fl
        ,wt.abc
        ,wt.xyz
    from
        wt_temp_t wt
    where
        <condition>
)
select  a
        ,b
        ,c

        from
        (
            select
                w.aa
                ,w.bb
                ,w.cc
                trxn w
            where
                <condition>
)included_trxn
 -- Left joins in case the acct is null or external
                        left outer join table
                        acct a_cp,
                        cust c_cp
    where
        <condition>
    type tab_bulk_select is table of bulk_select%rowtype;
    cur_bulk_select tab_bulk_select;

BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'truncate table AML_CAMBRS6_HUB_SPOKE_TMP';
commit;

open bulk_select;
LOOP
fetch bulk_select bulk collect into cur_bulk_select limit 50000;

FORALL i IN 1..cur_bulk_select.COUNT

insert /*+ append */ into AML_CAMBRS6_HUB_SPOKE_TMP (a,b,c)
values cur_bulk_select(i);

commit;
EXIT When bulk_select%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
CLOSE bulk_select;
```

Comment: It's likely that in your actual code there's a mismatch between columns selected from the cursor and those specified in the `insert into  (..)`

Comment: I double checked the column count is same

Comment: In my opinion, it would really help if you posted code that compiles. This is missing some parts, has two CLOSE statements ... it it difficult - for us, who have to **guess** what might be wrong - whether your problems are caused by missing parts or not. Therefore, please - rewrite it, make it as simple as possible (Scott's EMP and DEPT tables will be fine), edit your message and help us help you. Several people tried to assist, and you said that you already checked it. It **isn't obvious** when code we see is incomplete.

Comment: I posted the edited code as per your request. The code is complete and just missing few columns as per the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Its because in `trxn` you are fetching only 2 values `wt.fo_trxn_seq_id ,wt.pass_thru_fl`.

But in `select` clause `select w.aa ,w.bb, w.cc trxn w where <condition>` you are using `aa, bb, cc` and also missing `from` in statement.

Comment: The values in trxn table is correct, this is just for the example. I checked the select and insert have same count of records